# Android: OnePlus 6T Compass Gets "Stuck" Until Placed on Magnetic Mount and Removed

Tags: android, compass

Hello and thanks in advance for the help.

I am working on an app which provides range bearing to a particular spot based on GPS and compass.

From time to time (every week or so) I have noticed that the compass orientation freezes. I have installed a different compass app and, it doesn't freeze, but it is clearly giving a very wrong reading (for example, north indicated directly to the sun).

Similarly, Google Maps is showing the wrong reading. I am sure the bearing are wrong because if the sun was in the north we'd be really screwed :). Plus I have another compass on my watch, and it is OK, so I know where north really is.

I suspect the reason my app is frozen, and the other app is not frozen, is just because of the different animation approaches. The root cause appears to be that the sensor is "jammed" even though it is in a solid state.

I have tried recalibrating (maybe 40 times), shutting off the phone, resetting the phone, clear the app's memory, stopping the app, etc..

What I noticed today is that if I place my phone on its magnetic mount, all of a sudden the compass started working again once I remove it from the mount. So, to be clear, I am out in the woods many kilometers away from my magnetic mount when it is jammed but when I return to my car and put it on/remove it from the mount everything works fine again for a few days.

I have never had an electronic compass behave like this. Unfortunately google searches invariably point me to suggestions to recalibrate.

If it matters, the phone is a OnePlus 6T with Android 11, Oxygen OS 11.1.1.1

Thanks

Comment: Questions about topics other than development or programming, but related to Android, are not on-topic for Stack Overflow, but **may** be on-topic at https://android.stackexchange.com (and you're more likely to get a good answer there). Please review [the guidelines for posting in that community](//android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting there to ensure that your question is on-topic.

Comment: I literally wrote

"I am working on an app which provides range bearing to a particular spot based on GPS and compass."

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I probably should have written a more specific comment.  My apologies.  Basically, what I meant is that this sounds like an issue with your device rather than a problem with your programming, and you're more likely to get useful help from the folks on Android.SE who have experience helping fix device hardware/software issues, rather than the other programmers here who aren't as used to dealing with that sort of thing.  Or in other words: it seems unlikely that there's a programming solution to your problem.